# PHP MYSQL Same Number, Same Type, Different Results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having an issue I cannot for the life of me figure out.  To me it makes no sense, so I think I am obviously missing something, i just cannot see what it is.

I have a simple script...

```
$pid = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';

$pcjid = delete_user($pid);

try {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare ("SELECT aid_id FROM tbl_personcompanyitem_join WHERE pcj_id = $pcjid");
    $sth->execute ();
    while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
        $aid = $row['aid_id'];
    }

} catch (PDOEXCEPTION $e) {
    $err++;
    write_to_log($e);
}

delete_lot($aid);
```

For some reason, my sql query will not return any results when using a variable, but will if I hardcode a number in there. I have verified that the data is in the database to be returned, and by writing to a log file that...

1. The variable $pid has a value and is a valid value
2. The variable $pcjid has a value when the delete_user() function is
   returned
3. The sql query shows a value where $pcjid is
4. The variable $pcjid is an integer, which it should be
5. The variable $aid is undefined
6. delete_lot() is getting passed a null value
7. Everything works as it should if I hardcode a number in there, even
   if it is the same number that $pcjid says it is

I have been fighting with this for two days and cannot see what I am missing. I am hoping a fresh pair of eyes can see what i can not and shed some light  on this.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: in response to comments, I tried with binding also:

```
    $sth = $dbh->prepare ("SELECT aid_id FROM tbl_personcompanyitem_join WHERE pcj_id = :id");
    $sth->bindParam (":id",$pcjid);
    $sth->execute ();
```

but same result.

UPDATE: in response to andrewsi comment, here are some more results:

**TEST 1:**
setting this manually:    $pcjid = 19;
adding this to while:

```
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
    write_to_log("rowid=" . $row['aid_id']);
    write_to_log('row=' . $row);
    $aid = $row['aid_id'];
}
```

I get the following results:

- pcjid = 19
- rowid=25
- Array to string conversion
- row=Array
- aid = 25

**TEST 2:** WHEN I do the same test, but use a user that I know will return a value of 19 for $pcjid, I get the following results:

- pcjid = 19
- Undefined variable: aid
- aid =

So when using a the results I am getting back from the function, even though it is the same number I am hard coding, it doesn't enter the while loop.

UPDATE:
I also just tried this when using what i did in TEST 2 above.

```
$r = $sth->execute ();
write_to_log('r=' . $r);
```

and I get:  r = 1;

UPDATE:
So just for fun I tried a couple more things...

1. I tried converting the number to a string, and then back to an
   integer, both with the number returned from the function and the
   hardcoded number.  SAME RESULT.
2. I tried adding a 0 to the number, both with the number returned from
   the function and the hardcoded number.  SAME RESULT.
3. I converted both of them to a string. SAME RESULT.

Seriously, can anyone see what is happening here?  It is about to drive me nuts.

Comment: u missing parameter binding

Comment: Just tried binding, but the same result

Comment: @biggunn - does the code ever go into your `while` loop? Add in an echo to check. I'd also recommend checking the return value from your `execute` call to make sure it's not returning a false.

Comment: it goes into the while loop when I hardcode a number but not when using the variable.  I will test the return value of the execute.

Comment: @biggunn - what is the type of the column `pcj_id` in `tbl_personcompanyitem_join`? I can't see any reason why this would be failing in the way you describe, so I am admittedly clutching at straws.

Comment: @biggunn - also, your comment about `a user that I know will return a value of 19 for $pcjid`... Could you echo out the generated SQL that you're creating, just to be absolutely certain that it's being created properly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the parameters to the statement after preparing it:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare ("SELECT aid_id FROM tbl_personcompanyitem_join WHERE pcj_id = ?");
$sth->bind_param("i", $pcjid)
$sth->execute ();
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php